# Lightning components in community don't work

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am getting an issue when applying Lightning Components for Community:

I created a Custom Visualforce Page, on this page I added a few Lightning Components and they are working fine. 
I set the page to "Community Home", now I login as a Partner User but the data at the Lightning Components don't work.
I also implemented the forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes interface: 
Please help me how to do the Lightning Components can work on Community?

Thanks
Jerry

Comment: Need your code to see the issues.

Answer (score 2):

There is a domain related issue that we are working on that is Community specific. We have fixed this in Spring'16 already and are evaluating backporting the fix to Winter'16 patch.

Related post [Lightning Out for Visual Force in a community works in dev org but fails in sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97840/lightning-out-for-visual-force-in-a-community-works-in-dev-org-but-fails-in-sand)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using Winter's 16, my Visualforce Page is API version 35.0.

Comment: I am getting an error about "Service Unavailable" on my browser, here is the error:
"aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT 503 (Service Unavailable)
$Lightning.use @ lightning.out.js:42
(anonymous function) @ Portal:451 "

Comment: The backport has been approved and I am working on getting into the next Winter'16 patch that is supposed to deploy early next week. Nit much we can do under communities until then. You can of course continue to develop and test by accessing the VF page directly until then. After the patch is deployed to our service things should just work.

Comment: @DougChasman this is very important for us, too. Thanks for pushing this.

Comment: @DougChasman could you please confirm when the patch will be applied this week? We are really struggling, there are 100+ users just waiting to be migrated to the community. Thanks Jerry

Comment: Yes, the fix is in the patch for Winter '16 for this week - expected deployment to production tomorrow evening. The fix is one of a few so I do not have total control of the timing.

Comment: @ DougChasman: is the patch ready on production? seems it has not applied.

Comment: Not all instances have been upgraded yet - the rollout went very very late last night (especially for folks like me on the east coast). What instance is your org on?

Comment: @ DougChasman: our instance is NA20, please help us check if the update applied to the instance

Answer (score 1):

Fix for this should be on all instances now. We've also released a new Visualforce component to make this even easier (no need to worry about sessionID or base URLs). Documentation update will be out next week but this is the short version: just change:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
```

to:

```
<apex:includeLightning/>
```

and you should be good to go for all contexts where your Visualforce page can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The patch that @DougChasman mentions does seem to have rolled out now. I've been having the same problem and it has now gone in the production and sandbox orgs I've tried.

I have still been seeing a 503 response though even when using the new apex component but this is due to lightning.out.js being cached somewhere in the network infrastructure. I have browser cache disabled and get lightning.out.js code thats unchanged from before the fix, but appending ?x=x to the request gets different code. Having changed the community path it all works.

Comment: Martin you should no longer need to (or want to) specify base url /or session like this. Will you please switch to <apex:includeLightning/> and verify that this works and then could I ask you to delete this answer provided it does? Thank you

Comment: That workaround does still seem necessary on a dev org with <apex:includeLightning/> and a path in the community url. Removing  the baseUrl argument is still giving a 503 on the app load (path is not included on the request url). Haven't had chance to try a sandbox or production org yet.

Comment: (The sessionId here is not relevant to any of this by the way, I just happened to paste in some code that was passing that into the component to allow it to upload files with the rest api.)

Comment: Its a cache thing, I've updated the answer.